# EditText scrolling problems

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a ListView and in it i have Edit Text

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:lines="3"
    android:id="@+id/editTextComment"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/style002"/>
```

I dont't know why, but it's not scrollable, and there is no blue marker(copy,paste)
Also ListView has its own scrolls and maybe it's blocking the scroll of EditText

Comment: May be edittext is focusing i am not sure , you can try with set fucus false in edittext , if still have problem then provide whole layout here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes exactly Listview Block edittext scroll property. So better way is you have to display all data in listview at a time.so no need to scroll in Edittext...